# How to compute the joint spectrum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(A_{1},A_{2}, \ldots,A_{k})$ be  $k$  matrices  in $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Is  there  an algebraic  formula,  as  a  generalization of  "Determinant" for  $k=1$,  to  compute the  joint spectrum of $(A_{1},A_{2}, \ldots,A_{k})$?

The joint spectrum is the  union of  righ and  left  joint  spectrum. The  later is  defined as follows:

**Right joint spectrum=**  All $(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \ldots, \lambda_{k})$ such that the right ideal  generated  by  $(A_{i} - \lambda_{i}I)_{i=1}^{k}$ is not the  whole $M_{n}(\mathbb{R}).$

Moreover,  motivated by  Perron–Frobenius theorem we ask:

> Assume that all enries of  all matrices $(A_{1},A_{2}, \ldots,A_{k})$ are positive. Is there an element $(\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \ldots, \lambda_{k})$  of  joint spectrum with $\lambda \geq 0$?

Comment: If the right ideal generated by the $A_i -\lambda_iI$ is proper, then there exists $e =e^2\neq0$ such that left multiplication by $e$ kills the right ideal (since every right ideal of matrix rings over a field is of the form $fR$ for an idempotent $f$). Thus $e\cdot (A_i-\lambda_iI) $ are all zero, so the $A_i$s have a common left eigenvector—so a (left) invariant space. However, if we assume (as is generic) that the algebra generated by the $A_i$ is the entire matrix algebra, then this is impossible. We can easily find tuples of positive-entried matrices with this property.  So, no.

Comment: @DavidHandelman  Thank you very  much for your very interesting answer.According to your answer, I realize that , the following could be  a counter example $\begin{pmatrix}  1&1\\ 1& 1 \end{pmatrix}$  and  $\begin{pmatrix}  0&1\\ 4& 0\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $T=M_n(\mathbb{R})$. We have a polynomial map $f:\mathbb{R}^k\times T^k\to Hom_{\mathbb{R}}(T^k,T)$ which sends $((\lambda_i),(A_i))$ to the linear map $$(B_i)\mapsto \sum_i B_i(A_i-\lambda_i).$$
It holds that $f((\lambda_i),(A_i))$ is not surjective if and only if $(\lambda_i)$ is in the left joint spectrum of $(A_i)$.
The lack of surjectivity of $f((\lambda_i),(A_i))$ can be written in terms of the vanishing of some minors. This describes the left joint spectrum as a Zariski closed subset of an affine space, where the coefficients of the polynomials are given by polynomials in the entries of $A_i$. A similar thing can be done of course to the right joint spectrum, and since the union of Zariski closed subsets is Zariski closed, we get the result we want.

Comment: @Ehid  Thank you for your  answer. So  according to your  answer,  the  formula i guess is  $Det(\sum (A_{i}-\lambda_{i}) \otimes I))=0$.

Comment: Not exactly: you will get determinants of the minor matrices, which is not the same as the determinant you wrote.

Comment: If  we  identify $M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}} $ then the  matrix  representation of the  linear  map $X \mapsto AX$ is $A \otimes I$, your  linear  map is  a  sum of  such  miltiplication operatores. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by $A\otimes I$. In any case, you have here a linear map not from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ but from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2k}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. So you cannot describe this as a single determinant which vanishes, you should consider all the determinants of all the $n^2\times n^2$ minors.

Comment: Yes  I see. BTW, by $A \otimes  B$  I  mean the  tensor  product  of  matrices.